# Python won't let me import tensorflow.keras even though tensorflow and keras are both installed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've installed tensorflow and keras in every possible way I can think of, I have updated pip, used brew, tried a virtualenv but for some reason it won't let me import specific methods from tensorflow.keras (see image). What can I do?

[Import issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFzJj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import model_from_json
```

Comment: This worked thank you! Unfortunately I'm now having the same issue with opencv where I am trying to import CascadeClassifier (aka use it in the program) and it doesn't seem to recognize that as part of cv2...if you have any suggestions for that I would love to know haha!

Comment: Glad it helped. What's the error message and how are you importing opencv?

Comment: The code is being highlighted as an error and says "Cannot find reference ___ in '__init__.py' ". For example, when I try to initialize video capturing via cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0), it says "Cannot find reference 'VideoCapture' in '__init__.py'.

Comment: I'm afraid this would need a new question, with some code and details about the tools you're using, like the IDE.